# save cookies with same name but different values in php

Tags: php, cookies

I am designing a real estate website i have many ads in my website and when user click on a certain ad it goes to another page `viewmore.php` which gives user more details about that certain ad.

Now as you see in `viewmore.php` file I save ad's id in cookies and  send ad's id to the favorite page and user can review that post any time he or she wants in favorite page.

The problem:

consider that i visit this page `localhost/viewmore.php?ID=10` thus when you go to favorite page u see the ad data which belong to this id but when you visit another ad like `localhost/viewmore.php?ID=11` and you go to the favorite page you see the ad data which belong to `id=11` and previous add is gone. i want to save both of them in my favorite page or as a matter of fact save all the posts i visit.

how can i do that?

```
//reviewmore.php
<!doctype html>
<?php
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
?>
<?php 
$cookie_name = "favoritepost";
$cookie_value ="$ID";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
?>
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
(is_numeric($_GET['ID'])) ? $ID = $_GET['ID'] : $ID = 1;
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $ID");
?>
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result):
$price=$row['price'];
$rent=$row['rent'];
$room=$row['room'];
$date=$row['date'];
?>
<?php 
echo"price";
echo"room";
echo"date";
?>
</body>
  </html>
```

favoritepage.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
 <?php 
$cookie_name = "favoritepost";
?>
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT*FROM ".$db_table." WHERE idhome = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]");
?>
<?php $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result):
$price=$row['price'];
$rent=$row['rent'];
$room=$row['room'];
$date=$row['date'];
?>
<?php 
echo"price";
echo"room";
echo"date";
?>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Why not have an array as a cookie value?

Comment: @ Ryan Vincent hey man thank you for your answering as u see me and RiggsFolly worked a lot on this question but the first code in the below does not work for me could u please check it and give me your opinion thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the ID's as an array in your cookie like this for example, you have to `serialize()/unserialize()` or `json_encode()/json_decode()` the array into the cookie as it only supports text and not complex data

```
<?php
$ID = is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 1;

$cookie_name = "favoritepost";

if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    $kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
    $kookie = array();
}
if ( ! in_array($ID, $kookie) ) {
    $kookie[] = $ID;
}

setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($kookie), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
```

Now the last cookie entered I assume will be the one that you want to use in your query so just get

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$cookie_name = "favoritepost";
include("config.php");
if ( ! isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    echo 'NO COOKIE SET';
    exit;
}

$kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
$ID = $kookie[count($kookie)-1];
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE idhome = $ID");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result):
$price=$row['price'];
$rent=$row['rent'];
$room=$row['room'];
$date=$row['date'];

echo"price";
echo"room";
echo"date";
?>
```

Comment: i have a error
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings for this line
$kookie[] = $ID;

Comment: also you miss one parenthese in your code i assume it is like this :

Comment: `if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ){`
    `$kookie = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];`
`} else {`
    `$kookie = array();`
`}`

Comment: You will have to make sure you delete your existing scalar cookie. That would probably explain this error `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: no i delete my previous code but still it gives me a warning and error: 
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in---
 Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in

Comment: Delete cookies in the browser or change the time limit temporarily to 10 seconds so that it gets deleted normally

Comment: yes thank you it worked but now i can not retrieve id i mean this line
$ID = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name][count($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]-1)];
does not work could u please take a look at this

Comment: also i did not get this line too could u please explain it too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116995/discussion-between-user6362236-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: hey man how can i change my code thus it show all ads in my favorite page now i have to change the number or this line $ID = $kookie[count($kookie)-1];

Comment: How can it show all ads. Even if the query is getting more than one Ad, you only read one from the result set

Comment: yes i know.i think we have to put code in a while loop or something like this. what is your opinion?

Comment: like when we fetch multiple rows from database.

Comment: I guess I really dont understand what is going on here

Comment: consider a user visit two post in this case he or she wants to see both ads in favorite page not, only the last one. 
did u get it now?