# have an array as a cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

I am having a PHP code problem. As you see, I get an `id` from another page. I want to save these `id`'s in array based on cookies. I was able to do that, but I have a problem with it.

When I set the timeout (for example to 20 seconds) and refresh page: every 20 second it works fine, but if I refresh it in under 20 seconds it gives me the error below.

> Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

I do not know why; could you please help?

```html
<?php
$ID = is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 1;

$cookie_name = "favoritepost";

if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    $kookie = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
} else {
    $kookie = array();
}
if ( ! in_array($ID, $kookie) ) {
    $kookie[] = $ID;
}

setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($kookie), time() + (20), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
```

Comment: and "this error" is...?

Comment: @ Marc B thank you for your answering like i said in question it gives me this error
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: you never deserialized your array. EVERYTHING that comes out of $_COOKIES is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my last answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38307347/2310830

```
<?php
$ID = is_numeric($_GET['ID']) ? $_GET['ID'] : 1;

$cookie_name = "favoritepost";

if ( isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
    $kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
} else {
    $kookie = array();
}
if ( ! in_array($ID, $kookie) ) {
    $kookie[] = $ID;
}

setcookie($cookie_name, serialize($kookie), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
```

Comment: Why comprehend answers when you can just ask more questions?

Comment: yes man i do not know why but i did not see this part in your code 
    $kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
really really soory

Comment: @Devon Oh woops beg yer pardon

Answer (score 0):

The array is serialized when it is stored as a cookie.  So when you retrieve it, it is a string, not an array.  You need to unserialize it before you add more to it:

```
$kookie = unserialize($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
```